# Splitting a string conditional on another column

Tags: r, regex, for-loop, if-statement, extract

I would like to split a variable called `country` conditional on whether it has a year in it (Albania2009 vs. Albania).

In addition, where the variable does not have a year (i.e. Albania), I would like to copy the country name to `cname` and manually put a year in `cyear`.

```
   idstd   id    xxx        id1        country 
   <dbl+>   <dbl> <dbl+lbl> <dbl+lbl>   <chr>
 1 445801   NA      NA       7          Albania2009 
 2 542384 4616555 1163       7          Albania  
 3 445801   NA      NA       7          Albania2009 
 4 542384 4616555 1163       7          Albania
```

I first tried myself, making use of the fact that id is NA when country has a year in it:

```
CAmerica0306P$cyear <- NA
CAmerica0306P$cname <- NA
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
if (df$id[i]==NA) {
df[i,] <- separate(df, country[i], into = c("cname", "cyear"), -4)
} else {
df$cyear[i,] <- 2001
df$cname[i,] <- df$country[i,]
}
}
```

But it splits everything. After checking stackoverflow I tried:

```
df <- df %>% 
    extract(country, into=c("cname", "cyear"), regex="^(?=.{1,7}$)([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9].*)$", remove=FALSE)
```

but it does not fill the cells (still NA's).

Desired output:

```
   idstd   id    xxx        id1        country   cyear cname
   <dbl+>   <dbl> <dbl+lbl> <dbl+lbl>   <chr>   <dbl>
 1 445801   NA      NA       7          Albania  2009 Albania  
 2 542384 4616555 1163       7          Albania  2001 Albania  
 3 445801   NA      NA       7          Albania  2009 Albania  
 4 542384 4616555 1163       7          Albania  2001 Albania
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you provide reproducible example using dput() in R .

Comment: I am pretty sure all the info you need is in the post.

Comment: @Tom your question could be improved by adding **ready to use data**, provided as the result of `dput(YOUR_DATA)`. It's also unclear why you want `2001` when no year is prominent. Anyways, enough detail was given to provide an answer. Hope my answer helps!

Comment: Hi Andre, thank you for your answer. It worked perfectly. I am sorry not providing `dput`. I am using various very large databases which makes it very tedious to provide `dput`. It also almost never seems really necessary to answer any question. I do always make sure to provide a tibble, which I believe has almost every necessary info. Most people who ask for `dput`, just make that comment and then never return to the question. Most people who answer my question actually do not seem to mind. But I will try to improve on this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example data: (you should provide ready to use data)

```
df1<-
data.frame(country = I(paste0("Albania",c("",2007:2012,""))) )
```

code:

```
df1$cname <-sub("\\d+$","", df1$country)      #remove all numbers in the end

df1$cyear <-gsub("[^0-9]","", df1$country)    #remove everything that is not a number
df1$cyear[df1$cyear == ""] <- 2001            #where no year is prominent insert 2001

df1$country<- df1$cname
```

result:

```
#  country   cname cyear
#1 Albania Albania  2001
#2 Albania Albania  2007
#3 Albania Albania  2008
#4 Albania Albania  2009
#5 Albania Albania  2010
#6 Albania Albania  2011
#7 Albania Albania  2012
#8 Albania Albania  2001
```